# Postgres Query of an Array using LIKE

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am querying a database in Postgres using psql. I have used the following query to search a field called *tags* that has an array of text as it's data type:

```
select count(*) from planet_osm_ways where 'highway' = ANY(tags);
```

I now need to create a query that searches the *tags* fields for any word starting with the letter 'A'. I tried the following:

```
select count(*) from planet_osm_ways where 'A%' LIKE ANY(tags);
```

This gives me a syntax error. Any suggestions on how to use LIKE with an array of text?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-array.html) function to convert array to set of rows:

```
SELECT count(distinct id)
FROM (
    SELECT id, unnest(tags) tag
    FROM planet_osm_ways) x
WHERE tag LIKE 'A%'
```

The `count(dictinct id)` should count unique entries from `planet_osm_ways` table, just replace `id` with your primary key's name.

That being said, you should really think about storing tags in a separate table, with many-to-one relationship with `planet_osm_ways`, or create a separate table for tags that will have many-to-many relationship with `planet_osm_ways`. The way you store tags now makes it impossible to use indexes while searching for tags, which means that each search performs a full table scan.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it within the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM planet_osm_ways 
WHERE (
  0 < (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM unnest(planet_osm_ways) AS planet_osm_way
    WHERE planet_osm_way LIKE 'A%'
  )
);
```

Comment: This solution is the only one that preserves tags if we need to return it