# postgres query involving regex array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i've got this table:

```
create_table "packages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "sender_type"
  t.integer  "sender_account_id"
  t.integer  "sender_user_id"
  t.string   "address"
  t.text     "type"
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  t.string   "recipients",                     array: true
end
```

the recipient array takes the model type and id, separated by a comma, so like `["Manufacturer,4", "Retail,6"]`.

in my where query, i'm looking to find packages that include any recipients with the word "Manufacturer":

`Package.where("sender_type = ? and recipients.include = ?", "school", regex).`

just wondering if i'm anywhere close with this

Answer (score 0):

If the string that you're searching for is always in the first place in your array, you could access it like that:

`Package.where("sender_type = ? and recipients[0] LIKE = ?", "school", "Manufacturer").`

Not tested so you may need to adapt.

Comment: much appreciated!   i ended up ditching the entire concept

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to convert `recepients` to `text`:

```
Package.where("sender_type = ? and recipients::text LIKE ?", "school", regex)
```

Or you can use `unnest` function to conver an array to set of rows. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222285/7362128