# PSQL unnest function not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, unnest

I tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222106/postgres-query-of-an-array-using-like) but I'm still getting an error.

Query:

```
SELECT unnest(team)
FROM table_of_teams
WHERE team LIKE '%akg%';
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ unknown
LINE 5: WHERE team LIKE '%akg%'
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Table Structure:

```
                            Table "public.table_of_teams"
       Column       |            Type             |                   Modifiers                     
--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 teamid             | integer                     | not null default nextval('team_seq'::regclass)
 index              | integer                     | 
 name               | character varying           | 
 grouping           | character varying           | 
 hour_of_day        | integer[]                   | 
 day_of_week        | integer[]                   | 
 team               | character varying[]         |
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of `table_of_teams` please?

Comment: @Mureinik shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want to extract the teams that meet the given condition, you could put the `unnest` call in a subquery and apply the condition in the surrounding query:

```
SELECT single_team
FROM   (SELECT unnest(team) single_team
        FROM table_of_teams) t
WHERE single_team LIKE '%akg%';
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Didn't realize a nested query was required.