# How can I search for arrays that contain strings found in my search key?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

Say I have a Product table with a json array attribute called "name". For example, `Product.first.name == ["large", "black", "hoodie"]`. I want to search through my database for Products with names that contain words in my search query. So if I type in "large hoodie", Product.first should be returned in the results.

So first I have to turn the search key into an array of strings:

```
def search
  search_array = params[:search].split(" ")
  results = #???
```

but how can I search for Products with names that include values also contained in `search_array`? I've found documentation on how to search for values *within* arrays, but not on how to search for arrays themselves.

Comment: Is the column name a jsonb or just a serialized text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use, `@>` (contains) operator.

```
select * from products;
 id |  name   |              tags              |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  3 | T-Shirt | {clothing,summer}              | 2017-10-30 05:28:19.394888 | 2017-10-30 05:28:19.394888
  4 | Sweater | {clothing,winter,large,hoodie} | 2017-10-30 05:28:38.189589 | 2017-10-30 05:28:38.189589
(2 rows)


select * from products where tags @> '{large, hoodie}';
 id |  name   |              tags              |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  4 | Sweater | {clothing,winter,large,hoodie} | 2017-10-30 05:28:38.189589 | 2017-10-30 05:28:38.189589
(1 row)
```

Or, as an AR query,

```
2.3.1 :002 > Product.where("tags @> '{large, hoodie}'")
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (tags @> '{large, hoodie}')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 4, name: "Sweater", tags: ["clothing", "winter", "large", "hoodie"], created_at: "2017-10-30 05:28:38", updated_at: "2017-10-30 05:28:38">]>
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if the LIKE/ILIKE methods can be integrated with this?

Comment: however have a look up those threads. 

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117740/postgresql-like-query-on-array-field

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222106/postgres-query-of-an-array-using-like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as you are using `postgresql`, you can use gem [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search).

Add search scope in model:

```
include PgSearch
pg_search_scope :search_on_text_columns,
                 against: %i(name),
                 using: { tsearch: { prefix: true } }
```

For more details check out the [documentation](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#usage). Cheers!